# Is "ps -u" Really a Bad Syntax?

Tags: linux, shell, ps

IMHO `ps -u` shows a very useful output, much better than `ps -u $USER`:

```
$ ps -u
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
elastic   234897  0.0  0.0 105980  1336 pts/2    S+   Oct10   0:00 /bin/bash ./run.sh collector-json-1.conf
elastic   234899 48.7  7.1 10087120 4433104 pts/2 Sl+ Oct10 2804:11 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09_x64/bin/java -Xmx6144m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatin
:
```

compared to

```
$ ps -u $USER
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 234897 pts/2    00:00:00 run.sh
 234899 pts/2    1-22:44:04 java
:
```

1. But, why is it "bad syntax"? `/usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ` doesn't help much.
2. What would be a "proper syntax" to achieve the exact same output?

*In case it's important:*

```
$ uname -a
Linux h22k34.local 2.6.32-042stab044.17 #1 SMP Fri Jan 13 12:53:58 MSK 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: And now for the tough part: Which answer should get the checkmark?

Comment: Actually I thought I should let you, the users, decide. The one with the higher upvotes should get it. But, you are not making this any easier ;)

Comment: when both answers are equally good, I upvote both, and give the checkmark to the user with the lower rep, especially when the difference is more than 100k.

Comment: @FrankThomas done :)

Comment: On SysV-based systems (or ones whose `ps` comes from that line of things), I frequently use `ps -fu $USER`... getting `ps -f` output formatting which is somewhat similar to `ps u` formatting, yet also getting the specify-a-user thing.  In case you wanted both at the same time.

Comment: Use `ps u`, or `export I_WANT_A_BROKEN_PS=1; ps -u`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The correct syntax, *which returns the same output*, would be:

```
ps u
```

There is a good reason why modern syntax for `ps` is a mess.  Historically, there were two incompatible version of `ps`. Options with a leading dash were inherited from the AT&T Unix version of `ps`.  Options without a leading dash  were inherited from BSD.  The version of `ps` that Linux distributions generally use is GNU which has merged both sets of options together, as well as added its own set of options that start with a leading double-dash.

Thus, `ps u` is BSD-style and `ps -u $USER` is AT&T-style.  The fact that GNU `ps` allows you to run `ps -u` and, other than the warning, get the same output as `ps u` shows that GNU is attempting to make the best of a bad situation.

Comment: Actually, there is not a good reason for the mess.  There are several bad ones, and the purported dichotomy of "GNU" and "BSD" is a fallacy propounded by a Linux manual page.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511530/5132 .

Answer (score 84):

The `ps` command historically had wildly different syntax in BSD and System V Unix.

- In [BSD `ps`](http://www.retro11.de/ouxr/43bsd/usr/man/cat1/ps.0.html), the `u` option (no dash) takes no parameter and shows the "user-oriented output" with the additional columns.
- In [SunOS `ps`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SunOS+5.10&arch=default&format=html), the `-u` option (with dash) takes a username as parameter and only includes processes owned by that user, but without changing the display format.

(As another very common example, BSD `e` means "show environment", while SunOS `-e` means "show everyone's processes".)

[Linux *procps* `ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) tries to support both styles. So if you use the 'dash' option `-u`, it will expect it to be the SunOS "filter this user" option, *not* the extended columns option. The two are confused frequently enough, however, that *procps* tries to Do What You Meant – if the username is missing, it'll assume you gave it a BSD option but used SunOS syntax.

(There were in fact so many different variants of `ps` that the *procps* has an actual table of "personalities" to force ambiguous behavior to be interpreted as one style or another or yet another – *in addition to* knobs like "UNIX95", "CMD_ENV", "_XPG", "I_WANT_A_BROKEN_PS"...)

Comment: "I_WANT_A_BROKEN_PS" hah.

Comment: ...At first, I thought that was a joke.  [But nooooo...](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/wIO5K6N91IBt8nR8IfqV#ScOH7vyAGrCxCj5)

Comment: Hmm, as it turns out, this is exactly the option to hide the "ambiguous usage" the warnings that OP is seeing.